# Who scored the most penalties in one season in the UEFA Champions league

Tags: football, champions-league, penalty-shot

Which player scored the most penalties in one season in the UEFA Champions league?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several players with **four** scored penalties in one season. As three players (Immobile, Werner and Messi) already have scored three penalties this season (group stage 2020) there is a good chance of at least one of them beating this record.

All players who scored four penalties until season 19/20:

- Cristiano Ronaldo 2017/18
- Robert Lewandowski 2016/17
- Thomas Müller 2014/15
- Arturo Vidal 2013/14
- Lionel Messi 2011/12

The all-time leader is Cristiano Ronaldo with 19 scored penalties.

[Here](https://www.transfermarkt.com/uefa-champions-league/torschuetzenliste/pokalwettbewerb/CL/saison_id/2020/plus/1) is a list of all goal scorers, including appearances, assists and how many goals were penalties.